# Deleted Lambda Function Still Executing

Tags: function, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We have a aws lambda function that processes some data and incase there is an error it sends out an email.

We experienced a surge of email from the lambda function so we changed the script and disabled the part where it sends email.   Unfortunately we still see the emails comming in.

So we deleted the function and we still keep receiving the error emails.

How can the lambda function still be running.   Would i be experiencing charges since the function is running.

John

Comment: Is it still happening? The large quantity might have caused a queue of Lambda executions, which can only run at a default 1000 concurrent executions. So, it might take a while to clear out. However, it is unlikely to keep working after the function is deleted. See: [Managing Concurrency - Throttling Behavior - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html#throttling-behavior)

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have it deployed in other regions from which you have not deleted it?